# how to unzip rar files which are in remote server using ssis task

Tags: ssis

I have .rar files in network folder and I need to unzip rar files and store as .bak files into remote server. I have used execute process task and passed expressions but when I am executing task getting error as The process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0".

I have googled the error but did not find how to fix this. Please can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Below are the expressions I used

Executable : `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe`

Arguments : `x \\NETWORK-SQLBACKUP\ACCOUNTS\Monthly\CustomerDB\CustomerDB_backup_2015_08_31_203001_4545366.rar -o\\SDL-VR-DBSBACKUP\F:\Monthly bak files\CustomerDB_backup_2015_08_31_203001_4545366`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

7zip, error code 2 means 'fatal error'.
You may need to wrap the output file in quotation marks because it contains spaces.
A good way to test it is running it from the command line manually and make sure it works, once you are happy with the result you can try it from a SSIS task.:

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x \\NETWORK-SQLBACKUP\ACCOUNTS\Monthly\CustomerDB\CustomerDB_backup_2015_08_31_203001_4545366.rar -o"\\SDL-VR-DBSBACKUP\F:\Monthly bak files\CustomerDB_backup_2015_08_31_203001_4545366"

Comment: tried. now getting this error message The process exit code was "7" while the expected was "0".

Comment: I edited the answer to include the 7zip line as I believe it should be

Comment: still same error. when I execute this in cmd getting error Too Short Switch: -o

Comment: ok, i think the -o should be inside the quotations as well; I edited the answer

Comment: I tried myself and edited the answer in the way it worked for me; try again please and let me know

Comment: this time error appearing when executing in cmd is system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: please notice that in my latest edit I took the -o back outside the quotations and added quotation marks around the c:\program files\7-zip\iz.exe

Comment: I have used exactly same what you did, but same error again

Comment: another problem could be the UNCs, especially the output that includes a drive. could you please unzip it locally to rule out problems with UNCs?

Comment: I can able to unzip locally within same folder. but I want the .bak files copy to remote server folder.

Comment: i'm not too sure about the UNC format, please try F$ instead of F: in the output path and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Thanks. I can able to extract files but 7 zip console is opening when I execute package and asking password and only when I give password rar file is extracting files. is there any way to give password in execute process task so that to avoid giving manually?

Comment: Yes, parameter -p in 7z:  for example if the password is 123456 t -p123456