# How to unzip a file on another server using 7 zip?

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I'm using an SSIS package to unzip a file that's on another server. I've looked around for solutions and can only see answers for files that are on the same server. I found this answer but couldn't get it working - [how to unzip rar files which are in remote server using ssis task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700478/how-to-unzip-rar-files-which-are-in-remote-server-using-ssis-task)

I thought referencing the server like this would work in the arguments field on an execute process task, but it didn't:

x backup.gz "-o\\server\E$\folder\backup.gz"

I can use a batch file but it still doesn't work, I feel like I'm referencing the server wrong?

Comment: You need to put the correct server name, shared folders and most important have read/write access on that folder with the process account. What does it means "it still doesn't work" exactly?

Comment: Definitely have read/write access on that folder. When running is SSIS it exits with process code "2". Whenever I've tried to create a batch file it opens command line and shuts within a second. Do I need to add the drive? The comments on the question linked just don't seem to be clear as they change what they say a lot.

Comment: You are trying to debug way too many possible failure points at once. Here is how I would debug this problem. 1) Run 7zip directly from a command prompt.  If that works move on to step 2. 2) Run 7zip from a batch file.  If that works, move on to step 3. 3) Run the batch file from your SSIS package.

Comment: You are trying to extract file `backup.gz` from within `working directory` specified in SSIS configuration into a folder named `\\server\E$\folder\backup.gz`. Make sure that is what you want, and both file and folder exist (are you certain `backup.gz` is a folder?).

Comment: Try creating a batch-file containing something like `"C:\FULL\PATH\TO\7z.exe" x "C:\FULL\PATH\TO\backup.gz" "-o\\server\E$\folder\backup.gz" 1>"%userprofile%\testmsg.txt" 2>"%userprofile%\testerr.txt"` to capture any error messages into text files in `c:\users\username`.

Comment: I would not use an administrative share like this. It's possibly an authentication issue. I would share a specific folder and give the one necessary account access to the share and folder permissions. I assume the folder is not shared at all currently?

Comment: Sorry the backup is on the server. The file path is like this "\\server\folder\backup.gz" and the location I wish the extracted file to be in is "\\server\folder\backup.bak". The folder itself is shared with the server that the batch file is running on.

Comment: I've used a the batch file option and executing it from the SSIS package. Thanks for all your advice guys, it works now!